# Filtering String from Firestore database sends an error on SwiftUI

Tags: filter, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm working on implementing a search for a movies database stored in firestore using SwiftUI. I've tried doing filtering the movie names by the entered text as follows:

```
@ObservedObject var movies = getMoviesData()

...

ForEach(self.movies.datas) { movies in
  ForEach(movies.title.filter({"\($0)".contains(searchText.lowercased()) || searchText.isEmpty})) { item in
                                
     if let url = URL(string: movies.img) {
        AnimatedImage(url: url)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: bounds.size.width / 2 - 0.6, height: bounds.size.height / 2 - 0.2)       
     }
                                
  }
  .animation(.spring())
}

...

struct movies : Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var img: String
    var video: String
    var description: String
    var genre: String
}

class getMoviesData : ObservableObject{
    @Published var datas = [movies]()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData(){
        db.collection("movies").addSnapshotListener{ (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let mov = querySnapshot?.documents else{
                print("No movies")
                return
            }
            
            self.datas = mov.map{(queryDocumentSnapshot) -> movies in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let img = data["img"] as? String ?? ""
                let video = data["video"] as? String ?? ""
                let description = data["description"] as? String ?? ""
                let genre = data["genre"] as? String ?? ""
                
                return movies(id: id, title: title, img: img, video: video, description: description, genre: genre)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm receiving the following error on the second ForEach statement:

> Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') conform to 'Identifiable'

Movies.title represents a String output of each movie identified in the ForEach statement. How should I filter movies.title against the provided search text without invoking this error?

Answer (score 1):

I am little confused about your use of variable names.

```
 ForEach(movies.title.filter({"\($0)".contains(searchText.lowercased()) || searchText.isEmpty})) { item in
                                     
     }
                                
  }
```

In the above code movies.title is very misleading. Is there a title property on movies array. If you need to filter, you can perhaps check out the sample code below:

```
struct Movie {
    let title: String
}

let movies = [Movie(title: "Spiderman"), Movie(title: "Batman"), Movie(title: "Superman")]
let searchWord = "batman"


let filteredMovies = movies.filter { movie in
    return movie.title.lowercased().contains(searchWord.lowercased())
}

print(filteredMovies)
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes title is one of the fields of my Firebase firestore collection and is referenced using movies.title. The movie titles aren't stored locally hence I'm not sure how to apply your example. Thank you for the response though

Comment: I would start with refactoring the existing code. movies.title does not read nicely. When I read movies I think of an array and array cannot have a title property.

Comment: Sure thing, I will try to make that adjustment!